# Windows 7 repartitioning

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning

When I set up my laptop I didn't know what I was doing and allocated too much disk space to my recovery partition (D: drive).

Now that I am a little more familiar with it I would like to know how to reassign some of the space back to my main partition (C: drive). How can I do this?

I'm using Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do a backup of important data
2. Download and make a live (CD booting) copy of [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads) or download [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and make a bootable USB stick version of it
3. Read the site documentation about using GParted
4. Resize the desired partitions

Comment: +1 for mentioning GParted.  +1,000 for mentioning **backup** first.

Answer (score 0):

**[This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)** might be able to help you. You might be able to do it right from Windows. If you have administrative access, you can *resize* the recovery partition.

> **Shrink a Partition**
>
> In the Disk Management screen, just
>   right-click on the partition that you
>   want to shrink, and select “Shrink
>   Volume” from the menu.
>
> [image: shrinking a partition]

However, if you can't, look into downloading a running a **[GParted Live CD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)**.

Comment: That's not going to work.  `diskpart` will only shrink free space available at the end of the partition, leaving the unallocated space at the end of the drive.  It won't move the data so the newly unallocated space can be added to the C: drive.  At least not without switching to Dynamic Disks and having the partitions spanned, but that has other issues.